# How to purchase United Airlines domestic tickets from South Africa?

Tags: payment-cards, united-airlines

I am based in South Africa, and I want to purchase two domestic flight tickets (NY to Dallas) and see that under "Billing Address", my country is not listed. I'll be using my own personal, South African issued VISA credit card.

How do I purchase tickets for internal travel then?  Can I provide my family member's billings address instead?

Comment: Billing address is usually linked to the card.  You can't use someone else's address with your card; the charge would be declined.

Comment: It is likely that the company limits it foreign transactions to just a few countries or that it does not want to deal with countries it has had difficulties with in the past. Maybe you can buy a prepaid card in the USA or have a travel agency arrange things for you.

Comment: I suggest you use an online travel agent such as expedia. I can select a South Aftrica billing address for United flights

Answer (score 3):

On the United website, when you pick Africa as your region, this message appears:

> Online transactions cannot currently be completed with a billing address from Africa, and languages for this region are not available.
>
> For assistance with reservations, please contact your local United ticket office, or your travel agent.

So you can't book a flight on the United website with your credit card.

You might be able to ask a friend or relative (who lives somewhere other than Africa) to book the flight, and then pay them back.  If you are in the US, you might be able to purchase a prepaid debit card and book the flight using it (though I am not sure whether that will work).

You could also call United's South Africa office (phone number available on the United website) and try to book the flight through them.  There might be an extra charge.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that airlines often price tickets differently depending on where they are sold. Domestic US flights purchased in South Africa could well cost more than if someone bought them on the website in the US. I'd price it out both ways and try to have your family member buy the ticket for you if that works out cheaper.

Comment: Note that some airlines require the credit card used for booking at check in. I have no idea though if that is the case here.